# Using argparse arguments as keyword arguments

Tags: python, argparse

Let's say I have an `args` namespace after parsing my command line with argparse. Now, I want to use this to create some objects like this:

```
foo = Foo(bar=args.bar)
```

Unfortunately, I have the restriction that *if* a keyword argument is set, it must not be `None`. Now, I need to check if `args.bar` is set and act accordingly:

```
if args.bar:
    foo = Foo(bar=args.bar)
else:
    foo = Foo()
```

This is unwieldy and doesn't scale for more arguments. What I'd like to have, is something like this:

```
foo = Foo(**args.__dict__)
```

but this still suffers from my initial problem and additionally doesn't work for keys that are not keyword arguments of the `__init__` method. Is there a good way to achieve these things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
>>> defined_args = {k:v for k,v in args._get_kwargs() if v is not None}
>>> foo = Foo(**defined_args)
```

For example:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> args = argparse.Namespace(key1=None,key2='value')
>>> {k:v for k,v in args._get_kwargs() if v is not None}
{'key2': 'value'}
```

Note, however, that `_get_kwargs()` is not part of the public API so may or may not be available in future releases/versions.

Comment: what's the difference between `args._get_kwargs` and `args.__dict__`?

Comment: @mgilson -- you made me check: none really :)  `def _get_kwargs(self):
return sorted(self.__dict__.items())`. But I suppose if the module maintainer ever added non-keyword attributes to `_AttributeHolder`, the base class of `Namespace`, he/she/they would presumably exclude them from `_get_kwargs`.

Comment: In that case, maybe you should just use `args.__dict__.items()`.  `args.__dict__` is guaranteed to exist (since there is no way a `Namespace` can know what arguments it will have ahead of time, it can't implement `__slots__` as far as I can see).  And, I suppose, if you're really paranoid, you could subclass `Namespace` and pass that into `parse_args` too...

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [vars()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars):

```
args = parser.parse_args()
Foo(**vars(args))
```

vars([object]) returns the namespace as a dictionary