# Unpacking arguments from argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I've been writing some command line python programs and using `argparse` to do it. I've been structuring my code somewhat as follows.

```
def main(arg1, arg2):
    # magic
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('arg1')
    parser.add_argument('arg2')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(args.arg1, args.arg2)
```

It's really super irritating to have to call out `arg1` and `arg2` 3 times. I understand having to do it twice.

Is there some way to treat the namespace returned by the `parse_args` function as a tuple? Or better yet as a tuple and a dict for optional args and do unpacking?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('arg1')
    parser.add_argument('arg2')
    parser.add_argument('--opt-arg', default='default_value')

    args, kwargs = parser.magic_method_call_that_would_make_my_life_amazing()

    # I get goosebumps just thinking about this
    main(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-namespace-object

> This class is deliberately simple, just an object subclass with a readable string representation. If you prefer to have dict-like view of the attributes, you can use the **standard Python idiom, vars()**:

```
>>>
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo')
>>> args = parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'BAR'])
>>> vars(args)
{'foo': 'BAR'}
```

Note that one of the big advances, or changes at least, from `optparse` to  `argparse` is that positional arguments, such as yours, are treated the same as optionals.  They both appear in the `args` `Namespace` object.  In `optparse`, positionals are just the left overs from parsing defined options.  You could get the same effect in `argparse` by omiting your arguments and using `parse_known_args`:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
args, extras = parser.parse_known_args()
```

`args` is now a Namespace, and `extras` a list.  You could then call your function as:

```
myfoo(*extras, **vars(args))
```

For example:

```
In [994]: import argparse
In [995]: def foo(*args, **kwargs):
   .....:     print(args)
   .....:     print(kwargs)
   .....:     
In [996]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [997]: parser.add_argument('-f','--foo')
Out[997]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['-f', '--foo'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
In [998]: args,extras = parser.parse_known_args(['-f','foobar','arg1','arg2'])
In [999]: args
Out[999]: Namespace(foo='foobar')
In [1000]: extras
Out[1000]: ['arg1', 'arg2']
In [1001]: foo(*extras, **vars(args))
('arg1', 'arg2')
{'foo': 'foobar'}
```

That same `argparse` paragraph shows that you can define your own `Namespace` class.  It wouldn't be hard to define one that behaves like a dictionary (for use as `**args`) and as namespace.  All `argparse` requires is that it works with `getattr` and `setattr`.

```
In [1002]: getattr(args,'foo')
Out[1002]: 'foobar'
In [1004]: setattr(args,'bar','ugg')
In [1005]: args
Out[1005]: Namespace(bar='ugg', foo='foobar')
```

another standard Python feature lets me pass `vars(args)` as a tuple:

```
In [1013]: foo(*vars(args).items())
(('foo', 'foobar'), ('bar', 'ugg'))
{}
```

For a similar answer from last January: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34932478/901925

[Neatly pass positional arguments as args and optional arguments as kwargs from argpase to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34932052/neatly-pass-positional-arguments-as-args-and-optional-arguments-as-kwargs-from-a)

There I give ideas on how to separate out 'positionals' from 'optionals' after parsing.

---

Here's a custom namespace class that includes, in its API, a means of returning itself as a dictionary:

```
In [1014]: class MyNameSpace(argparse.Namespace):
   ......:     def asdict(self):
   ......:         return vars(self)
   ......:     
In [1015]: args = parser.parse_args(['-f','foobar'], namespace=MyNameSpace())
In [1016]: args
Out[1016]: MyNameSpace(foo='foobar')
In [1017]: foo(**args.asdict())
()
{'foo': 'foobar'}
```

---

Another idea - use one of the multiple `nargs` (2,'*','+') for the positional argument.  Then you have only one name to type when passing it to your function.

```
parser.add_argument('pos',nargs='+')
args = ...
args.pos # a list, possibly empty
foo(*args.pos, **vars(args))
```

Answer (score 8):

You can see a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161269/using-argparse-arguments-as-keyword-arguments).

**Edit**: Looking for a way that would not use an internal method, I found [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27181165/426790) which suggested using `vars()`. This works quite well:

```
import argparse

def main(arg1, arg2):
    print arg1, arg2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('arg1')
    parser.add_argument('arg2')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(**vars(args))
```

Comment: This is a GREAT answer.... I'd rather be troubled by the library design than rely on something that isn't part of the public api because I'm a weeny and I finish last in life.

Comment: Cheers @BenHoff :-) You can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer if it works for you.

Comment: sorry I missing a _but_ in there. This is a great answer.... **but** I'd rather be troubled by the library design than rely on something that isn't part of the public api because I'm a weeny and I finish last in life.

Comment: You could also do `**args.__dict__`

Answer (score 5):

What is wrong with doing

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # do argparse stuff as above
    main(args)
```

That is, why are you so hung up about giving `main()` positional arguments?

To be honest, I usually do the argument parsing either a) [for small scripts etc.] at the beginning of the module, which provides me with a variable that's in the scope of all functions or b) [usually] inside `main()` if I use your idiom:

```
def parse_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('arg1')
    parser.add_argument('arg2')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

def main():
    args = parse_arguments()
    # do stuff with args.arg1 and args.arg2
```

Comment: I don't want to have to pack args into a tuple for my main function if I import/call it from another package. I do love that `parse_arguments` method call. I do love that indeed.